# Similar types: Cannot specialize a non-generic definition

Tags: ios, swift, realm, reactive-swift

I have a Controller where I need to import two pods.

```
import Realm
import ReactiveSwift
```

Problem is that both have a type named `Property`.

Now if I use that with importing both pods then it gives me compile time error `Cannot specialize a non-generic definition`.

For workaround,

I created a separate file and added extension to controller with importing Realm in that only. And kept ReactiveSwift in controller file. This helps me to prevent the error. But is this the best way?

Comment: You can use `Realm.Property` or `ReactiveSwift.Property`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the compiler to be able to decide which `Property` element you want to use, you have to add the namespace. In this case:

- `Realm.Property` to use the `Property` element from `Realm`
- `ReactiveSwift.Property` to use the `Property` element from `ReactiveSwift`

Comment: Simple solution :) hence +1 Though for cleaner approach you can have type alias I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

So here problem is 'Property' is available in RealmSwift as well and ReactiveSwift as well.

So here if you want to use Realm property as above answer suggest that you
can add `Realm.property` or `ReactiveSwift.Property` to access element.

Apart from it you can make **typealias** as well and also you can divide your code into two files using **extension**